# PHP качество кода

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Есть php код:

```
public static function load() : void
{
    $config = new ...;
    $config = $config->getData();

    $throw = function() : void
    {
        throw new \ConfigException ("Invalid config.");
    };

    self::$param1 = $config["core"]["param1"] ?? ($throw)();
    self::$param2 = $config["core"]["param2"] ?? ($throw)();
    self::$param3 = $config["module"]["param3"] ?? ($throw)();
    self::$param4 = $config["module"]["param4"] ?? ($throw)();
}

public static function getParam1() : bool
{
    return self::$param1;
}

public static function getParam2() : string
{
    return self::$param2;
}

public static function getParam3() : int
{...}

/*и т.д.*/
```

Он проверяет значения в массиве, и если их нету, то выбрасывает исключение `($throw)()`, если есть, то это значение присваивается в статическое свойство класса.

На мой взгляд, сейчас проверка значения и выбрасывание исключения выглядит ужасно. Как это можно оформить получше?

Comment: ну сделайте через конфиг какой-нибудь типа `[ 'param1' => "core.param1", ... ]`

Comment: В чём смысл этого статического класса? У вас же уже есть класс конфига с методом getData...

Comment: @vp_arth тот видимо чтением занимается исключительно. вообще самое стрёмное тут  пока что названия параметров `param1` и т.д.

Comment: Названия параметров, надеюсь, тут только для примера. Меня смущает type-hinting в геттерах и отсутствие проверки типов при разборе)

Comment: [инспекция кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info)

Comment: Ну и конфиг надо передавать в функцию а не создавать в нутри.

Answer (score 4):

Говорят, что лучший код не тот, в который нечего добавить, а тот, из которого нечего убрать. Если вы хотите провалидировать структуру массива конфига, убедившись что он содержит необходимые ключи -- сделайте именно это. Если вы хотите провалидировать значения параметров, с которыми собираетесь работать -- сделайте именно это. В конце концов, не важно как именно вы бросаете исключение, важно зачем и почему вы его бросаете.

Сделайте сообщение об ошибке более информативным (какой ключ отсутствует, в каком конфиге). Убедитесь что ваши проверки действительно необходимы в этом подозрительном классе. Избавтесь от лишних зависимостей. Убедитесь что сам подозрительный класс необходим.

Comment: Начав с последнего предложения, можно сэкономить кучу времени)